How can I scale this curve?
I have a problem with my scale. How can I fix?
b<- data.frame(OBS=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
               MB= c(0.3042,0.3009,0.29,0.295,0.292,0.290, 0.28,0.26,0.242,0.24),
               MC=c(0.282,0.286,0.289,0.293,0.296,0.299,0.30, 0.32, 0.325,0.34),
               END=c(0,0.008,0.0154,0.023,0.030,0.038,0.0463,0.06,0.19,0.231))

B_plot<- ggplot(b, aes(x= END,y= MB/MC, color= Legenda))+
  geom_line(aes(y= MB, col="MB"))+
  geom_line(aes(y= MC, col="MC"))+
  labs( x= "END", y= "MB / MC")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0:0.12,3)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.28:0.32,4))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.05765 )

I need x [0, 0.12] and y [0.28,0.32]

With seq are you looking for something like seq(0, .12, by = .06) and seq(.28, .32, .01)?

If you want a sequence from 0 to 0.12 with 3 breaks, you can use
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.12,length.out = 3)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.28,0.32,length.out = 4))

If you also want to limit the axis, you can use the argument limits inside the scale_ functions
